# List of metrics for dates

Tags: machine-learning, string-metrics

I am given a set of pairs of dates and would like to extract features I can put into an machine learning algorithm.

Thus far I have already written two different metrics, however I didn't find much literature on that topic. I know there is a lot of literature about on computing the distance or similarity of strings. There are even python packages offering various algorithm. However I have not found something similar for dates.

Does someone know, if something like this exists? If yes, what and where?

Specifics for the dates: They have the form: "DD-MM-YYYY" with the letters representing each a digit in 0 to 9, or being left empty. For example: 0-0-0 would be as valid as 3-12-2017

Comment: Usually we choose features informed by some knowledge of the meaning of the two dates, the learning task, and how the class might relate to the inputs.  Can you edit the question to add that context?  Without giving us that context, this seems like an open-ended brainstorming exercise without any criteria for evaluating answers, and those usually aren't suitable here; see our [help/dont-ask].  Requests for software recommendations/packages are also off-topic here, though requests  for techniques or algorithms are fine.

Comment: @D.W., of course. I will adjust the question to your remarks and be more specific.